# Is ServletRequest::setAttribute safe in terms of web service security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security, servlets

#### Short Version

Is `javax.servlet.ServletRequest`'s method `setAttribute(<key>, <Object>)` only used as a means of passing objects between methods in Java code?

#### Long version

Let's say I have a `javax.servlet.Filter` implementation to handle all logged in users' authentication using cookies:

<sup>in Spring Boot</sup>

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class AuthFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
        Cookie[] cookies = null;
        if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            cookies = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getCookies();
        }

        Optional<User> user = mySessionAuthMethod(cookies);
        if (user.isPresent()) {
            request.setAttribute("user", user.get());
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Then later, I can avoid manual authentication in all of the Web API methods, and just check the `user` attribute. Example of a `@RestController`'s method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/profile")
@CrossOrigin(origins = {MyProperties.ORIGIN}, allowCredentials = "true")
public ResponseEntity getProfile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String user = request.getAttribute("user");
    if (user != null) {
        return myGetProfileResponse(user);
    }
    return myNotLoggedInResponse();
}
```

#### My questions are:

- **Is this form of authentication secure?** What I mean is, are the attributes in the `ServletRequest` only added and used in Java for communication between methods, or could they be added to the request already before reaching the server?
- **Is this way of authentication using `Filter`s a good practice to avoid duplicate code?**

#### Additional Explanation

The real reason of doing this is not *only* authentication. I have also `Filter`s which need to process each and every request and pass objects to the `Controller`s. What I definitely want is that none of these objects and information can be forged even by a person who knows the implementation of the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the answer from the [documentation of `getAttribute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String))

> Attributes can be set two ways. The servlet container may set attributes to make available custom information about a request. For example, for requests made using HTTPS, the attribute `javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate` can be used to retrieve information on the certificate of the client. Attributes can also be set programatically using [`ServletRequest#setAttribute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)). This allows information to be embedded into a request before a `RequestDispatcher` call.

So according to this (if there is no missing information), it should be completely safe to pass custom objects and know that they were always created by the server.